# flutter : how to get value from stateful widget from another stateful widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

my problem is like this , i use step because this is multi step form. i cant use bloc because it is originally for base64 string for upload image

```
classAA extend state<classA>
late final ClassB ClassBBB= ClassB();

 Step(
       content: classBBB,
       state: _stepState(1),
       isActive: _currentStep == 1,
     ),


String? stringB = classBBB.getStringB();
```

this is classB

```
class classB extends StatefulWidget {
static final theKey = GlobalKey<_PhototakeState>();
@override
  State<classB > createState() => classBB();

  String? stringB () {
    return theKey.currentState?.stringB!;
  }

}
classBB extend state<classB>{

 String? stringB;
}
```

how to get stringB from class i declared for content on step, because this is wrong, i keep getting null on this even after i give value to it

Answer (score 0):

Try passing TextEditingController

classA

```
classAA extend state<classA>
var stringB = TextEditingController();  //add this
late final ClassB ClassBBB = ClassB(string: stringB);  //edit this

 Step(
       content: classBBB,
       state: _stepState(1),
       isActive: _currentStep == 1,
     ),


String? stringB = stringB.text;
```

classB

```
class classB extends StatefulWidget {
static final theKey = GlobalKey<_PhototakeState>();
final TextEditingController string;  //add this
classB({require this.string});  //add this
@override
  State<classB > createState() => classBB();

  String? stringB () {
    return theKey.currentState?.stringB!;
  }

}
classBB extend state<classB>{
 late String stringB = widget.string;  //edit this
}
```

you can also pass Function

classB

```
final Function(String) setString;
classB({required this.setString})
///////
classBB extend state<classB>{
 //call setString(value) when needed
}
```

classA

```
late final ClassB ClassBBB = ClassB((stringB){
   //you have the value here
});
```